# How to fix "array type expected found java.util.arraylist"?

Tags: java, android

Given the function as below, AndroidStudio gives an error in the labeled line:

```
array type expected found java.util.arraylist
```

I also tried to use `get` instead of a direct referencing, but then Android Studio is telling me something that `setItems` cannot be resolved. The code is here:

```
protected void multiSelect(final ArrayList items) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Selection")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.i("Select", "Selected entry: " + items[item]); // error here
                }
            });

    builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change

```
Log.i("Select", "Selected entry: " + items[item]);
```

to :

```
Log.i("Select", "Selected entry: " + items.get(item));
```

and change

```
protected void multiSelect(final ArrayList items)
```

to

```
protected void multiSelect(final ArrayList<String> items)
```

**UPDATE:**

the `setItems` method of the `DialogBuilder` expects an `array`, not an `arrayList`.

Comment: I have trying to tell that I tried this without success.

Comment: One sec... ArrayList of what ?

Comment: The error message is: Cannot resolve method 'setItems(java.util.ArrayList, anonymous android.content.DialogInterface..OnClickListener')

Comment: You should specify the type of the objects that your arrayList will hold reference to, like this : "final ArrayList<int> items" , for the example

Comment: With both suggestions I get the error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'items'" ... on all three occurrances of the variable 'items'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94847/discussion-between-jdev-and-alex).